# What Crystals should I use for Sniper/Gunslinger?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I am working on leveling up a Sniper, and I want to know what stat my Color Crystals should increase. Out of the 4 Cartel ones (Endurance, Crit Rate, Power, and Expertise), I ruled out Expertise and Endurance. But, I don't know which to pick out of the last 2. Should I go with Power or Crit Rate (for a DPS Sniper/Gunslinger)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 4.0, the below has changed — you always want Crit instead of Power.  See http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=844210

---

This completely depends on your current and desired stat distribution.  Most people stick with Power crystals but there's no reason you can't use fewer Crit mods/enhancements with Crit crystals.  [This guide](http://dulfy.net/2014/01/10/swtor-sniper-dps-class-guide/) has some recommended stat levels (about 150 Crit, rest in Power).  The current gear tiers (and most past ones) tend to give a ton of Crit so it often makes sense to take Power where you have the option.

Only hilts/barrels affect Weapon Damage so crystals, like other mods, purely add stats.